# Add child(LinearLayout) views to LinearLayout in android in a paritcular order

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am new to android development and I want to programatically  add LinearLayout views to the parent LinearLayout. And while doing so , I want to see them sequentially. That is the view that gets added first should be first , the view that is added second should be second and so on.
I tried doing it with

```
   HolderLayout.addView(view, index)
```

where index goes on incrementing, but it is not working for me. The view that i add first is shown second in the list. What should I do?
Outline of my code is :

```
    int index = 0;
    View Row1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.childView, null);

    //populate the appropriate data on the child Row and add it to the holder layout.

    holder_layout.addView(Row1 , index);
    index++;
    Set<Integer>keys = MyMap.keySet();

    for(int i : keys){


          View row = View.inflate(this,  
                                   R.layout.childView, null);

          holder_layout.addView(row , index);
          index++;

   }
```

where am I going wrong.

Comment: Define not working.  What isn't working?  What's actually happening?

Comment: the row that I am adding outside of the for loop is the last item that I am getting, in fact it should be the first ? right? as I am adding it at index = 0 ?

Comment: if you are using linear layout with orientation vertical it will automatically add new views sequentially

Comment: yes , Linear layout is vertical, it is not adding sequentially!

Comment: <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/holder_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    ></LinearLayout>

Comment: Don't use the addView with an index, use the addView without it.  It will automatically add it sequentially.

Comment: Tried Both, But its not working!!

Comment: I dont see any different in each rows? How do you know the added second is show first?

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
holder_layout.addView(row , new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

i dont think you have to specify the index as the default behaviour is to add above as you want

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, something that would have been affecting this code is incrementing `index` at the end of the loop. `Row1` would get added at position 0, then the first iteration of the loop would assign the first `row` to index 0 as well.
My guess as to what that would do, is to add `row` in before `Row1`, and update the indices accordingly; so on the second iteration of the loop, where it's using `index=1`, that puts it in just before `Row1`, and so on until the final result looks something like `ViewGroup { row[0], row[1], row[2] ... row[n] Row1 }`.
Given that's the behaviour you claimed to see, I dare say this is the true problem with your code. Although as mentioned, you should probably use `addChild(View)` - with no index, relying on the default behaviour to add it at the end. Unfortunately, the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) doesn't specify this, but I have just tested it and confirmed that's how it works.